# Android - Click Toolbar that is overlayed by a view

Tags: android

Here's my current situation: I can't click on the toolbar because there is a view that is overlapping it intercepting the touch responses. I'll expand: I'm making a music app. In the music app, there is a list of songs that is beneath the toolbar. However, once you click on a song, a panel opens up and slides up over the toolbar and continues into a transparent status bar. Pictures of this will be attached.
Now, obviously because this view is overlapping the toolbar I cannot actually use the toolbar for any touch events. But I need to. I cannot move the view below the toolbar because then my sliding up panel is limited to beneath the toolbar instead of overlapping it. If there is anyway to get around this, please let me know. I'd very much appreciate it.

So, in my current situation, I thought maybe I'd be able to touch the portion of the view that covers the toolbar and send that data to the view that contains the toolbar so I can detect touches on the toolbar. However, I cannot figure out how to do this, or even if it is possible.

My question is: How can I detect touches in the view beneath another view?

Here are the pictures:
Here is the list of songs:

[image: List of songs]

And here is when the song panel is opened(I'm using an image of a tiger for any song that doesn't have art at the moment):
[image: Song panel opened]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wtf? 
You want that your user can touch on the toolbar which is not visible at the moment because its overlapped by another view? What kind of user would expect such a user experience?

I mean:

1. How does the user even know that he can click on a not visible element ^^
2. If the user magically knows somehow that he can click, how does he know where exactly he has to click. For example, he could also click on one of the toolbar menu items, but if he clicks a few pixel more left, then he would click on toolbar item 1 instead of toolbar item 2.

However, you have three possibilities:

1. You can make the overlapping view not clickable by `overlappingView.setClickable(false);`.
2. You could add a transparent view with an OnClickListener that has the same width and height as the toolbar over the overlapping view. In the OnClickListener you could simply invoke the desired method like `onOptionsItemSelected()` (fake the required parameters) or use an `EventBus` for communication.
3. Similar to the 2. option add a transparent view, but instead of setting a `OnClickListener` set a `OnTouchListener` by extending from View) and forward the MotionEvent to the Toolbar by calling `toolbar.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);`

Comment: You misunderstand. The first picuture - the one where the toolbar is visible - is where I want the user to be able to click. Not in the second one. I will disable the touch on the toolbar when the song panel is up. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for that, yes in that case you simply have to call `toolbar.setClickable(false)` manually and set it to true afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is what is seen in Play Music and Nex Player. When you open a song, the panel scrolls above the toolbar. I don't know how they are doing it, but with the library I'm using the panel to scroll must be in the same parent view as the list of songs, therefore forcing me to have my parent view match_parent and causing this issue.

Comment: I guess you are using umanos libary: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

They are using a ViewDragHelper from the android support library. Is not as magic as it seems :D You may consider to accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to detect touch events of a view beneath another view you could set onTouchEvent of the foreground view to false. However, I advise you to rethink the layout in order to put the Toolbar on top so the users can see it otherwise they don't know what they are clicking on.